# In PHP given an extended date string, how can I extract the month Year in long format?

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

My attempted solution was:

```
$date = "Nov 30 2009 03:00:00:000PM";
echo date("F Y", strtotime($date));
```

Expected result should be: "November 2009"

Any other simple solutions?

Comment: `03:00:00:000PM` makes no sense. If you correct the source of that string, to `03:00:00`, I think `strtotime()` will work.

Comment: So what's the question, because the result IS November?!?!

Comment: I can't control the source of the datetime returned :(

Comment: was unable to test on my local box because of "Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. My mistake it appears to work despite error

Comment: well if that's not working for you (it does for me on 5.3.x) then you have to realize "garbage in, garbage out" so you need to parse/clean the input.  Perhaps using regex, then sent it to  strtotime().  Even splitting it up by space, then you only need to fix the time, which you can split by colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a regex could do it, here's something you might understand easier

```
$date_bad = "Nov 30 2009 03:00:00:000PM";

$piece_date = array();
$piece_date = explode(' ', $date_bad);
$date_good = $piece_date[0] .' '. $piece_date[1] .', '. $piece_date[2] .' ';

$piece_time = array();
$piece_time = explode(':', $piece_date[3]);

// check if the last part contains PM
if ( is_numeric(strpos($piece_time[3], 'PM')) )
{
    $ampm = 'PM';
}
// check if the last part contains AM
elseif ( is_numeric(strpos($piece_time[3], 'AM')) )
{
    $ampm = 'AM';
}
// no AM or PM is there, so it's a 24hr string
else
{
    $ampm = ''; 
}

$date_good .= $piece_time[0] .':'. $piece_time[1] .':'. $piece_time[2] . $ampm;

echo date("F", strtotime($date_good));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set  ('Etc/GMT-6');
$unixtime = strtotime($date_bad);
$date = date("F Y",$unixtime);
echo $date;
```

[Time Zones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

Comment: Can't get simpler than strtotime!

Comment: The question's example already used strtotime() and it wasn't working.